# How to select Multiple options from RadioGroup Buttons?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

it is possible to select multiple options from radiogroup buttons in android plz give some solution.
this my code in this code i can only select one radio button from the group plz give solution for select more then one selection.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/ChoiceText" />

    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:background="#abf234"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >

        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sound"
            android:text="@string/Sound" />

        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vibration"
            android:text="@string/Vibration" />

        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/silent"
            android:text="@string/Silent" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/chooseBtn"
        android:text="@string/Choose" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton sound, vibration, silent; 
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // find which radio button is selected
                if(checkedId == R.id.silent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Silent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(checkedId == R.id.sound) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Sound", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Vibration", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        sound = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
        vibration = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.vibration);
        silent = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.silent);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find which radioButton is checked by id
                if(selectedId == sound.getId()) {
                    textView.setText("You chose 'Sound' option");
                } else if(selectedId == vibration.getId()) {
                    textView.setText("You chose 'Vibration' option");
                } else {
                    textView.setText("You chose 'Silent' option");
                }   
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: use checkboxes instead of radio buttons for multiple selection..

Comment: Radio button designed to select on option among all options. to select multi options use checkbox

Comment: just remove radio group and use radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a radio group, just use some collection of radio buttons. RadioGroup is meant for selecting one from the list of radio buttons. So your xml will look like this after the changes

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="@string/ChoiceText" />



    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sound"
        android:text="@string/Sound" />

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vibration"
        android:text="@string/Vibration" />

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/silent"
        android:text="@string/Silent" />



<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myRadioGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/chooseBtn"
    android:text="@string/Choose" />
```

See that the radio group is removed.

Comment: As per @malli's comment above, it is better to use checkboxes for multiple selections, not radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

Please use checkbox if you want to have multiple entries. :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html